# filemtime() not working in Windows PHP-CLI

Tags: windows, php, filemtime

I just got PHP-CLI working on my Windows machine so I could create scripts using PHP.  However, I'm trying to write a script to cleanup my Firefox downloads folder of files older than X number of days, but I can't seem to get the filemtime() function working.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
function deleteOldFiles($dir, $days) {
  $mydir = opendir($dir);
  while(($file = readdir($mydir)) !== false) {
    if($file != "." && $file != ".." && (filemtime($dir.$file) <= time() - ($days * 86400))) {
      //unlink($dir.$file) or DIE("Failed to delete $dir$file<br />");
      echo filemtime($dir.$file);
    }
  }
  closedir($mydir);
}
```

And upon running this I get the following error for every file:

```
Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for E:\My Documents\Downloadsphp-5.3.0-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.msi in E:\_scripts\cleanupDownloads\cleanupDownloads.php on line 10
```

From the research I've done, filemtime() should work in Windows.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you post the declaration of $dir, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for E:\My Documents\Downloadsphp-5.3.0-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.msi in E:\_scripts\cleanupDownloads\cleanupDownloads.php on line 10`

You're missing a backslash `\` between the directory and the filename. Don't forget to escape it on Windows (`\\`) or just use the forward slash (`/`) or PHP's `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant.

**edit**

And have a look at [scandir()](http://ch.php.net/scandir), [glob()](http://ch.php.net/glob) or [DirectoryIterator](http://ch.php.net/directoryiterator).